# get text from <p> on a website with class or id in python

Tags: python, html

is there a way in python, to get the text from a

element on a website with classname or id?
I want to check if a text-element on a website has the same text as a string.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: try Beautiful Soup 4 https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can, using beautiful soup.

For example, you can refine your search to only find those divs with a given class:

mydivs = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "class_to_find"})
Take a look here : https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/